# 502 Bad Gateway on asp.net core 3.0 hosted in ubuntu 18.04 TLS with nginx

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, nginx

I published .NET CORE application to ubuntu 18.04 TLS with nginx but when I try browse I get 502 Bad gateaway.
I followed this tutorial : [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

and when I try to navigate to my website I get the 502 ERROR.
My server IP is: 185.162.127.7

Comment: What does the nginx error log say?

Comment: @hyvte I'm new to linux ,how do I check that?

Comment: Probably somewhere near `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: Have you found the problem ? I get the same problem but I replaced the port by 5900 in both side. I can't figure it out. I'm work on Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS + .NET 8.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try **dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000**, if it fails you get the 502 code.